# Insert Charts Into Individual Cells

Tags: graph, google-sheets

**The Issue:**
Graphs cant be inserted into cells like images can.

**The Request:**
The feature "=Image("URL",2)" Should also be available for charts.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to build simple charts within an individual cell using the SPARKLINE function. [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en) is the documentation.

Here is a simple example:

[image]